# Get save path of form within a project

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is it possible to get the path that a form exists in for the project?

I have a bunch of forms which I arrange in a tree view to help user navigation.  At the moment I have an attribute that I apply to the form's class which tells it the path to display the form under.

To keep them a bit organized in the project, I also create a similar folder structure and save the forms in those.

Just had the thought of de-duplicating that by simply using the path that the form is saved in the project to set the hierarchy in the tree view but googling and going through all the properties of the form and form's type doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Is the folder structure equal to the namespace structure? If so, all you'll need is the FullName of the type.

Comment: Thought about doing it that way too but atm, they're all in the same name space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
I found a way of doing this but, be warned, it is ugly.

You could have a look at this gem (available in .NET 4.5) [CallerFilePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute.aspx):

```
Public Shared Function GetFilePath() As String
    Return GetFilePath2()
End Function

Private Shared Function GetFilePath2(
    <CallerFilePath> Optional sourcefilePath As String = Nothing)

    Return sourcefilePath

End Function
```

The private function returns the physical path of the file that caused the call. That is why the public function wraps the private function.

Add these to each Form and you'll be able to get the physical file path of the form/class.

I made the functions Shared so you would not have to instantiate the form just to get its path. Unfortunately you cannot create a base class that contains this method and inherit all your forms from that because that would return the path of the base class. So you would need to create these functions in all your Forms... It is ugly but it does what you wanted.

On second thought: you could put the private function in a helper class as an extension method so you would only need to put the public function in each form.

**Old answer**

The folder structure of the solution in Visual Studio is not available to the application.

So the only way to fix this is by entering the stucture yourself, write some logic (macro?) that will extract the folder structure or by keeping the namespace in sync.

**IF** the namespace reflects the same structure you can simply use the FullName of the type:

```
 Dim t As Type = GetType(Form1)
 Console.WriteLine("The full name of the form is {0}.", t.FullName)
```

And you could use `String.Split` to break the full name into the parts of the namespace.

**EDIT**
(I moved this to a note because it is not relevant to VB but might be useful to C# users looking for a similar feature)

**In C# (NOT in VB)**: when you create a folder structure in a Visual Studio solution, the types you create in those folders will become the namespaces of these types. Note that the namespaces will not be updated when you manipulate (rename folders, move files) the solution items.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your second paragraph is incorrect for VB.NET. I think it's only C# where the folder structure is mirrored by the namespaces. (But I might be wrong, so I'm not editing your answer or anything.)

Comment: Anyway, the real answer is in the very first line. When you distribute the app, all of your individual project folders and forms are not going to be there, so whatever code you write that relies on this will break.

Comment: @CodyGray - I'll test that right now and edit my answer if needed. Thanks, I guess I'm too defaulted to C# :)

Comment: Darn, I'm in VB so don't get the name space even so think I'll rely on my current method of custom attributes for the class.

Comment: A custom attribute can work too but, like all other solutions, you'll need to maintain it by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the ugly function!  Too bad can't just add it to my base class for all the forms.  At the moment I add the attribute to all the forms so not too much worse to just add the function.  Will give it a go.

Comment: The difference between the attribute and the function is that you need to update the attribute when you move the file.

Comment: On second thought: you could put the private function in a helper class as an extension method so you would only need to put the public function in each form.